# header declaration error C++

Tags: c++

I have misunderstanding with header declaration. Please help m:

My cpp file:distanceMatrixFunc.cpp

```
float  DistanceMatrix::distanceMatrixFunc(int particleNumber,float xPos [], float yPos      
[], float zPos []) 
{
    int j, k  = 0;
    distanceMatrix_x[] = new float*[particleNumber];
    distanceMatrix_y = new float*[particleNumber];
    distanceMatrix_z = new float*[particleNumber];
    distanceMatrix   = new float*[particleNumber];

    for (int i = 0; i < particleNumber; i++){
    distanceMatrix_x[i] = new float[particleNumber];
    distanceMatrix_y[i] = new float[particleNumber];
    distanceMatrix_z[i] = new float[particleNumber];
    distanceMatrix[i] = new float[particleNumber];
}
```

distanceMatrixFunc.h function:

```
class DistanceMatrix {
    float distanceMatrix_x;
    float distanceMatrix_y;
    float distanceMatrix_z;
    float distanceMatrix;
    int particleNumber;
    float xPos ;
    float yPos ;
    float zPos;
    float distanceMatrixFunc( int  particleNumber, float xPos , float  yPos , floatzPos);
};
```

The problem is in my cpp file :
    float  DistanceMatrix::distanceMatrixFunc(int particleNumber,float xPos [], float yPos
    [], float zPos [])
**error** declaration is incompatible with float distanceMatrix

Comment: And also I have no idea for what purpose we declare int * function() {} using pointers,   instead of normal declaration int  function() {}

Comment: Have you already read the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration in your header file expects three `float` variables, your definition in your .cpp file expects three `float` arrays. Either change the declaration in your header file to expect three arrays:

```
float distanceMatrixFunc( int  particleNumber, float xPos[] , float  yPos[] , floatzPos[]);
```

or the definition in your .cpp file to expect three `float`s:

```
float distanceMatrixFunc( int  particleNumber, float xPos , float  yPos , float zPos) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: And another question why do we use pointer to pointer for method declaration instead of traditional. for example ** main() {}.

Comment: It is the return type of the function. You wouldn't want to do that in `main`, but in other functions, i.e. `int * function()`, it means that the function returns a pointer to an `int` (i.e., an `int *`).

Comment: float  distanceMatrix_x[] = new float*[particleNumber];

Comment: I have another error : initialization with {} expected another object

Comment: The correct syntax for this statement is `float *distanceMatrix_x = new float[particleNumber]`. You want to declare a pointer to a `float`, i.e. `float *distanceMatrix_x`, and set it to point to an array of `float`s, i.e. `new float[particleNumber]`.

Comment: The alternative, if you want an array instead of a pointer, is to use `float distanceMatrix_x[particleNumber]`. This just declares an array instead of a pointer.